# Displaying images from sd card in android

Tags: android, bitmap, gallery, lazy-loading

I have an application which needs to display around 50 images saved in the sd card.Each image file is encrypted and of size 600kb. So i will need to decrypt the image before showing it in a gallery widget.This loading is taking a large amuont of time(SD card read time + decryption time). I want to load the images in an efficient way(faster)
The solution I have in mind is something like that is there in the default android gallery application. Here when we swipe across images quickly, it will initially show a blurred version of the image.Then after 1 or 2 seconds the full image is shown. How should i go ahead to implement this way of 'incremental image loading'. Is there any other suggestion to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't implement that if the image is encrypted. You cannot know anything about the data until the image is fully decrytpted.

What you can do is decrypt all images at once and make a cache of them so you don't have to decrypt everytime.